# Grep a list of words from pairs of files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

i have a file with a list of Identifier that i have to grep from another file. I have to do this for a pairs of files (several like 100 pairs). The files look like:

A.not.txt.duplicated:

```
chr1_937201_937501  
chr1_937501_937801
```

A.not.txt:

```
chr1_937201_937501  329 1  
chr1_937201_937501  144 1  
chr1_937501_937801  329 1  
chr1_937501_937801  144 1  
chr1_1875601_1875901    764 1  
chr1_1875601_1875901    183 1  
chr1_2246701_2247001    377 1  
chr1_2246701_2247001    194 1  
chr1_937201_937501  0   0  
chr1_937201_937501  0   0  
chr1_937501_937801  0   0  
chr1_937501_937801  0   0  
chr1_1875601_1875901    0 0  
chr1_1875601_1875901    0   0  
chr1_2246701_2247001    0   0  
chr1_2246701_2247001    0   0
```

Output:

```
chr1_937201_937501  329 1  
chr1_937201_937501  144 1  
chr1_937501_937801  329 1  
chr1_937501_937801  144 1
```

I know that I can do by:

```
grep -f A.not.txt.duplicated A.not.txt > A.not.txt.duplicated
```

but the problem is that i have several pairs and i would like to make this in a loop.

Any Idea is really appreciated.

Comment: Which name patterns do the files have? A.not.txt.duplicated ... Z.not.txt.duplicated and A.not.txt ... Z.not.txt?

Comment: ENCFF002DDT.bed.sorted.bed.length_peaks.score.bed.header.not.txt.duplicated  and ENCFF002DDT.bed.sorted.bed.length_peaks.score.bed.header.not.txt  then another pair for example is  ENCFF002DDS.bed.sorted.bed.length_peaks.score.bed.header.not.txt.duplicated  ENCFF002DDS.bed.sorted.bed.length_peaks.score.bed.header.not.txt  the file ending with *.duplicated has the list of words to grep..

Comment: Your command `grep -f A.not.txt.duplicated A.not.txt > A.not.txt.duplicated` won't work at all because `A.not.txt.duplicated` will be truncated to zero bytes before `grep` even starts.

Comment: It starts in theory because i used it and i have written the input and the output in the post..  Are you sure it will not work?

Comment: @fusion.slope The first thing the shell does when it parses the line is to look for redirections like `>`. It then goes on to truncate the file that you redirect to. _Then_ it executes the command.

Comment: @Wildcard as JJoao suggested in the last answer, that is based on my initial question formulation, it works fine. Why removed me points? Anyway the points are not the problem, but the problem is that i was saying right as they were saying right in this other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863301/how-to-grep-with-a-list-of-words

Comment: @Wildcard Oh now i see, the name of the file with the list of words to grep is the same of the name of the file in the output: "A.not.txt.duplicated". Now i have understood. I cannot put the same name of a file in the input as name of file in the output. Finally!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use [join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html)

```
for f in *.not.txt.duplicated; do
  join <(sort "$f") <(sort "${f%.duplicated}") > "$f.out"
done
```

If you really want the ".duplicated" files overwritten by the results, as indicated in your example command, add `&& mv "$f.out" "$f"` onto the end of the `join` line.

Comment: `for f in *.not.txt; do grep -f "$f.duplicates" "$f" > "$f.out" ; done`

Comment: but the guys said that it is not possible to use grep -f for these reasons: "Your command grep -f A.not.txt.duplicated A.not.txt > A.not.txt.duplicated won't work at all because A.not.txt.duplicated will be truncated to zero bytes before grep even starts."  Is there a difference on this and in what i wrote in my question?

Comment: anyway @JJoao it works your way, i do not see the point of why they removed me 2 points saying that it is wrong. Thanks i will make this clear to them.

Comment: @fusion.slope, your main idea is correct, and your question makes sense. But any command writing to is arguments (like `grep ... a > a`) will not work. (all our solutions are writing to a different file). Wildcard, sorry to put comments in your answer...

Comment: Well the concept is correct @JJoao also you re-direct the output in your loop and this is exactly what i said that work for one file. Anyway does not matter.

Comment: I would put your solution as answer @JJoao because is the real output of the question.